# Displaying mediator analysis with LaTeX (TikZ-pfg maybe?)

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, statistics

I want to "draw" a mediator analysis with LaTeX, e.g. with TikZ. Unfortunately, I did not find any template for such a graphic; plus, I am lacking of skill to do it on my own (but very willing to learn!). Thus, I cannot offer a MWE! :(

The graphic shown below is made with Microsoft PP and displays some random variable names and values which should be replaceable with other variable names and values...

[image: Example]

Can someone reproduce such a mediator model with TikZ?
I also wonder if the font in the graphic will be the same like my document settings?

Comment: The font will be the same. You can have a look at the tutorials in the [TikZ manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) to get started... even if you provide a minimal example that doesn't do anything, just loads the correct packages, it will help us here :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I won't provide explanations but suggest you to read pgfmanual. There are nice tutorials there as commented by darthbith. What you want can be easily done.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw,text width=1in,align=center}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[mynode] (m){Mediator};
    \node[mynode,below left=of m](a) {Variable A};
    \node[mynode,below right=of m](b) {Variable B};
    \draw[-latex] (a.north) -- node[auto,font=\footnotesize] {$b=-0.56$, $p=0.04$} (m.west);
    \draw[-latex] (m.east) -- node[auto,font=\footnotesize] {$b=-0.44$, $p<0.001$} (b.north);
    \draw[-latex] (a.east) --
            node[below=3mm,font=\footnotesize,align=center] {Direct effect, $b=0.55$,
                 $p=0.03$ \\ Indirect effect, $b=0.16$, \SI{90}{\percent} CI [ 0.04,0.36]}
                 (b.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's one for two mediators:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw,text width=1in,align=center}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[mynode] (m1){M1};
    \node[mynode, right=3cm of m1] (m2){M2}; % Manual adjustment of sep
    \node[mynode,below left=of m1](a){X};
    \node[mynode,below right=of m2](b){Y};
    \draw[-latex] (a.north) -- node[auto,font=\footnotesize] {A}(m1.west);
    \draw[-latex] (m1.east) -- node[auto,font=\footnotesize] {B} (m2.west);
    \draw[-latex] (m2.east) -- node[auto,font=\footnotesize] {C} (b.north);
    \draw[-latex] (a.east) --
            node[below=3mm,font=\footnotesize,align=center] {Direct effect, $b=0.55$,
                 $p=0.03$ \\ Indirect effect, $b=0.16$, \SI{90}{\percent} CI [ 0.04,0.36]}
                 (b.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Multiple serial mediators]

And another for two parallel single mediators:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw,text width=1in,align=center}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[mynode] (m1){Mediator 1};
    \node[mynode,below left=of m1](a) {Variable A};
    \node[mynode,below right=of m1](b) {Variable B};
    \node[mynode,below = 2.5cm of m1] (m2){Mediator 2};

    \draw[-latex] (a.north) -- node[auto,font=\footnotesize] {A} (m1.west);
    \draw[-latex] (m1.east) -- node[auto,font=\footnotesize] {B} (b.north);
    \draw[-latex] (a.east) --
            node[below,font=\footnotesize,align=center] {C}
                 (b.west);
    \draw[-latex] (a.south) -- node[below,font=\footnotesize] {D} (m2.west);
    \draw[-latex] (m2.east) -- node[below,font=\footnotesize] {E} (b.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Parallel mediation diagram]